# Run 64 bit windows command from 32 bit java

Tags: java, windows, registry, 32bit-64bit, runtime.exec

I'm working on a java SWT application which needs to show the ODBC drivers installed in the local windows machine(64 bit). I came up with a reg query statement which will do that.

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources" /f *
```

when I run this command in command prompt I'm getting the expected output. But when I run the same command from 32 bit java, the reg query fails. Here is the sample code.

```
String cmd = "reg query \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources\" /f *";
        System.out.println(cmd);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        line = null;
        BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = err.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Output

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

Upon some reading I found that windows has Registry Redirection which is preventing my 32 bit java to use 64 bit registry and 64 bit reg.exe.

I tried to hardcode the path for 64 bit reg.exe in the system32 folder but it is still failing.

```
String cmd = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\reg.exe query \"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources\" /f *";
```

Anyway to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When run from the command line the `cmd.exe` shell strips the unnecessary quotes. When run directly from Java the quotes are left in and the resulting argument designates a non-existent (and invalid) key.

Comment: @JimGarrison its not because of the quotes. I have checked it by removing the quotes and ran it again

Comment: I tried by removing the quotes like you suggested. `String cmd = "reg query HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources /f *";` The output this time is incorrect syntax. I tired to access another value from the HKLM tree and it worked. `String cmd1 = "reg query \"HKLM\\HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0\" /v ProcessorNameString";`

The root cause looks like the architecture difference between java and windows.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the help guys. i found the solution. I have to use sysnative folder to access 64 bit tools from a 32 bit application.

so i updated my req query statement to this

```
String cmd = "C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\reg.exe query \"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources\" /f *";
```

output

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources
jbb    REG_SZ    IBM Integration (9.0.0.1) - DataDirect Technologies 7.0 64-BIT Oracle Wire Protocol
```